# How to change Worker Service interval time from external file when service is already installed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on `.NET Core` 'Worker Service' project to implement service for Windows & Linux OS.

Service reading data from external `config.xml` file like credentials/urls. I want to add interval time too in config file so that in future if I want change interval time(ex. every hour to every 2 hour), I will just update config file, I not need to modify and recompile the code.

I am using [Coraval](https://docs.coravel.net/) library for scheduling. Setting `interval` time in `Main` method. My doubt is when I will change `interval` time in config file(being read in `Main` method), how will it get assigned for further executions? for `Windows` and `Linux`.

How often `Main` method getting called so that it will read new scheduling time from config file?

This is my code

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var schedulingConfig = GlobalSettings.ReadIntervals(out List<intervalValue> intervalvalues);
    string intrvaltype = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in schedulingConfig)
    {
        if (item.Name == "true")
        {
            intrvaltype = item.Execution;
            break;
        }
    }
    IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    host.Services.UseScheduler(scheduler =>
    {
       //Remind schedular to repeat the same job  
        switch (intrvaltype)
        {
            case "isSignleHourInADay":
                scheduler
               .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
               .Hourly();
                break;
            case "isMinutes":
                scheduler
               .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
               .EveryFiveMinutes();
                break;

            case "isOnceInADay":
                scheduler
               .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
               .Daily();
                break;

            case "isSecond":
                scheduler
               .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
               .EveryThirtySeconds();
                break;
        }  
    });
    host.Run();
}
```

Where should I keep my code so that it will do the needful?

**Edit1**

`Program.cs` class

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        host.Services.UseScheduler(scheduler =>
        {
            scheduler
            .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
            .Hourly()
            .When(() => IsRun("isSignleHourInADay"));

            scheduler
            .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
            .EveryFiveMinutes()
            .When(() => IsRun("isMinutes"));

            scheduler
            .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
            .Daily()
            .When(() => IsRun("isOnceInADay"));

            scheduler
            .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
            .EveryThirtySeconds()
            .When(() => IsRun("isSecond"));

        });
        host.Run();
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
          Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .ConfigureServices(services =>
              {
                  services.AddScheduler();
              }).UseSerilog().UseSystemd();

    static Task<bool> IsRun(string intervalType)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var schedulingConfig = ConfigData();
            string configIntrvalType = schedulingConfig.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "true")?.Execution;
            return intervalType == configIntrvalType;
        });
    }

    public static List<intervalValue> ConfigData()
    {
        return new List<intervalValue> { new intervalValue { Execution= "isSignleHourInADay", Name="false"},
                                         new intervalValue { Execution= "isMinutes", Name="true"},
                                         new intervalValue { Execution= "isOnceInADay", Name="false"},
                                         new intervalValue { Execution= "isSecond", Name="false"},
                                         new intervalValue { Execution= "isMultipleHoursInADay", Name="false"},
        };
    }
    public class intervalValue
    {
        public string Execution { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`ReprocessInvocable.cs` class

```
public class ReprocessInvocable : IInvocable
{
    private readonly ILogger<ReprocessInvocable> _logger;
    public ReprocessInvocable(ILogger<ReprocessInvocable> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public async Task Invoke()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        Log.Information("Invoke has called at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
    }
}
```

**Edit2**
This is `StatusConfigTest2.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parameters>  
<intervalValue>
<Definition Execution="isMultipleHoursInADayVal" Name="1AM,4PM,6AM"></Definition>
<Definition Execution="isSignleHourInADayVal" Name="4AM"></Definition>
<Definition Execution="isMinutesVal" Name="5"></Definition>
<Definition Execution="isOnceInADayVal" Name="5PM"></Definition>
<Definition Execution="isSecondVal" Name="20"></Definition>
</intervalValue>
<intervalType>
<Definition Execution="isMultipleHoursInADay" Name="false"></Definition>
<Definition Execution="isSignleHourInADay" Name="false"></Definition>
<Definition Execution="isMinutes" Name="true"></Definition>
<Definition Execution="isOnceInADay" Name="false"></Definition>
<Definition Execution="isSecond" Name="false"></Definition>
</intervalType>
</parameters>
```

Method to read xml file

```
public static List<intervalValue> GetFilterProducts1(out List<intervalValue> 
intervalValueout)
{
    List<intervalValue> IntrvalValueList = new List<intervalValue>();
    List<intervalValue> IntervalTypeList = new List<intervalValue>();

    try
    {
        FileStream fs = null;
        var files = new List<string>();
        files.Add("D:/ProductStatusConfigTest2.xml");
        //file2
        //file3
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw;
            }
        }

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(fs);
        XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/parameters/intervalValue");
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                IntrvalValueList.Add(new intervalValue { Name = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["Name"].Value, Execution = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["Execution"].Value });
            }
        }
        XmlNode node2 = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/parameters/intervalType");
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                IntervalTypeList.Add(new intervalValue { Name = node2.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["Name"].Value, Execution = node2.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["Execution"].Value });
            }
        }
        intervalValueout = IntrvalValueList;
        return IntervalTypeList;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        intervalValueout = IntervalTypeList;
        return IntervalTypeList;
    }
}
```

Comment: The main in this case is only ever called once so i'm not sure if you can actually alter the scheduling when your host in running. I feel like if that were the case, the coravel library  would expose a service that could be injected into your worker service app. What you could do is switch to hangfire instead; https://www.hangfire.io/ which allows you to create / alter jobs from anywhere.

Comment: also can't you simply restart the service once you downloaded your new configuration? that way you'll load the new settings

Comment: @sommmen - To restart service we need to run cmd as admin, we do not have admin access in our machines. is hangfire is free?

Comment: What version of .net core is used?

Comment: @cassandrad - .Net Core 3.1, where worker service template introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I saw in Coravel, it has `When` method that could be your solution:

First define a method that say which Interval is valid to run based on your config:

```
static Task<bool> IsRun(string intervalType)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var schedulingConfig = GlobalSettings.ReadIntervals(out List<intervalValue> intervalvalues);
        string configIntrvalType = schedulingConfig.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "true")?.Execution;
        return intervalType == configIntrvalType;
    });
}
```

Then add `When` to your Invocables this way:

```
host.Services.UseScheduler(scheduler =>
{
    scheduler
    .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
    .Hourly()
    .When(() => IsRun("isSignleHourInADay"));

    scheduler
    .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
    .EveryFiveMinutes()
    .When(() => IsRun("isMinutes"));

    scheduler
    .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
    .Daily()
    .When(() => IsRun("isOnceInADay"));

    scheduler
    .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
    .EveryThirtySeconds()
    .When(() => IsRun("isSecond"));
});
```

---

**Edit**

Here's full code that should work:

**`Program.cs`**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        host.Services.UseScheduler(scheduler =>
        {
            scheduler
            .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
            .Hourly()
            .When(() => IsRun("isSignleHourInADay"));

            scheduler
            .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
            .EveryMinute()
            .When(() => IsRun("isMinutes"));

            scheduler
            .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
            .Daily()
            .When(() => IsRun("isOnceInADay"));

            scheduler
            .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
            .EverySecond()
            .When(() => IsRun("isSecond"));

        });
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddScoped<ReprocessInvocable>();
                services.AddScheduler();
            });

    static Task<bool> IsRun(string intervalType)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var schedulingConfig = GetFilterProducts(out List<intervalValue> intrvalValueList);
            string configIntrvalType = schedulingConfig.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name.ToLower().Trim() == "true")?.Execution;
            return intervalType.ToLower().Trim() == configIntrvalType.ToLower().Trim();
        });
    }

    static List<intervalValue> GetFilterProducts(out List<intervalValue> intervalValueList)
    {
        List<intervalValue> IntervalTypeList = new List<intervalValue>();
        intervalValueList = new List<intervalValue>();

        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("D:/ProductStatusConfigTest2.xml");
            XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/parameters/intervalValue");
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                {
                    intervalValueList.Add(new intervalValue { Name = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["Name"].Value, Execution = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["Execution"].Value });
                }
            }
            XmlNode node2 = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/parameters/intervalType");
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                {
                    IntervalTypeList.Add(new intervalValue { Name = node2.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["Name"].Value, Execution = node2.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["Execution"].Value });
                }
            }
            return IntervalTypeList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            intervalValueList = IntervalTypeList;
            return IntervalTypeList;
        }
    }

    class intervalValue
    {
        public string Execution { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**`ReprocessInvocable.cs`**

```
public class ReprocessInvocable : IInvocable
{
    private readonly ILogger<ReprocessInvocable> _logger;
    public ReprocessInvocable(ILogger<ReprocessInvocable> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public async Task Invoke()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214640/discussion-on-answer-by-arman-ebrahimpour-how-to-change-worker-service-interval).